# Intellij can not parse pom.xml with $revision. Maven works

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, parent-pom

`${revision}` tag can be used in pom.xml as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html).

Having this directory structure:

```
fix
├── pom.xml
├── parent
│   └── pom.xml
└── example
    └── pom.xml
```

**pom.xml** has:

```
<project>
    <groupId>intellij</groupId>
    <artifactId>fix</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>

    <properties>
        <project.parent.basedir>parent</project.parent.basedir>
    </properties>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>parent</module>
        <module>example</module>
    </modules>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
</project>
```

**parent/pom.xml** has:

```
<project>
    <groupId>intellij</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.0.0</revision>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>intellij</groupId>
        <artifactId>fix</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
</project>
```

And **example/pom.xml** :

```
<project>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>intellij</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
        <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
</project>
```

IntelliJ reports:

[image]

Whereas `mvn` on terminal parses it well and works.

This breaks a lot of stuff in IntelliJ.
I tried this with IntelliJ 2019.2

Comment: You should move the properties definition for the version property from your parent into the root of the project (fix artifact). Furthermore I strongly recommend to prevent using a parent which is a module as well as a parent...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a hint. If you do a simply `mvn clean` on command with the structure you will see this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent 1.0.0 ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.146 s]
[INFO] example 1.0.0 ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] fix ${revision} .................................... SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this shows there is something wrong here...cause the version property can not be resolved in the root pom....and this is the reason why IDEA IntelliJ tells you that there is something wrong....as you see the root project in the last line which is indicator there is an issue.

If you move the revision property correctly into the root project (fix) than you will see this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ example ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for fix 1.0.0:
[INFO] 
[INFO] fix ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.106 s]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] example ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.255 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-28T20:56:22+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this output you see the `fix` at the first line which is correct.

I strongly recommend to change your structure correctly and do not use `<relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>` in your `example` project which is an indicator your directory structure does not represent your real structure which you have created within your pom files.

This should result in a structure as given in the example project on github which  I have create:

https://github.com/khmarbaise/so-question-1

Apart from that please add the `flatten-maven-plugin` as described in the documentation to your project otherwise you will fail in cases you are using `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean deploy`

Comment: First, thank you for taking your time having a look at this issue.
That fixes the problem. It may have seem obvious to you, but the project I inherited has 187 pom.xml files, and I struggled a bit to bring this simplified example in order to have a fix for it.
I will try to change the structure but it depends if that fits with my development agenda. We already have flatten-maven-plugin enabled and many, many others... Cheers and thanks again!

Comment: I know how the real life looks cause I have done several projects with a much larges pom (800+ modules etc.) ...so no surprise.

Comment: Wow, 800+! That is a much `bigger ball of mud`... ;-)